# User profile login solution for Java/Spring app

Tags: java, facebook, spring, authentication

I'm developing a web application in Java, using Spring Framework. I'm adding personalization to my site, and I'd like to provide my users the best experience. Features I'm looking for:

- Support for logging in using popular services (at least Facebook and Google)
- Support for creating a username/password
- Support of tying multiple credentials (i.e. the same account can have FB, Google and username/password)
- Reset password feature
- Remember-me feature
- Nice login widget (like Stackoverflow's for instance)
- Secure storage of passwords
- JSP integration (i.e. login tag, conditional "is-logged-in", "has-permission-x" tags)
- Support for integrating in my schema
- Mobile support (usable from mobile browsers)
- Open source

I realize Spring Security/Spring Social has some of this (and they overlap a bit).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, spring-security, spring-social, spring-mobile, openid4java, and a [javascript openid library](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20openid&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) cover your requirements. But you still have to write code and configure stuff. It's not "ready-to-use". You can start with [spring-roo](http://www.springsource.org/spring-roo) that will generate some skeleton project on which you can build forward.